# Implementing RSA in C#

Tags: c#, rsa, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I'm currently trying to implement a class to handle secure communications between instances of my app using RSACrytoServiceProveider class. 
First question : is it a good idea implement a single class to handle sender/reciever roles or should i split the roles into individual classes ?. This is what i have done so far:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Agnus.Cipher
{
    public class RSA
    {
        private byte[] plaintextBytes;
        private byte[] ciphertextBytes;
        private RSACryptoServiceProvider rSAProviderThis;
        private RSACryptoServiceProvider rSAProviderOther;

        public string PublicKey
        {
            get { return rSAProviderThis.ToXmlString(false); }
        }

        public RSA()
        {
            rSAProviderThis = new RSACryptoServiceProvider { PersistKeyInCsp = true }; 
            plaintextBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(PublicKey);
        }

        public void InitializeRSAProviderOther(string parameters)
        {
            rSAProviderOther.FromXmlString(parameters);
        }

        public byte[] Encrypt()
        {
            return rSAProviderThis.Encrypt(plaintextBytes, true);
        }
        public byte[] Decrypt()
        {
            return rSAProviderThis.Decrypt(ciphertextBytes, true);
        }
        public byte[] Sign()
        {
            using (SHA1Managed SHA1 = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                byte[] hash = SHA1.ComputeHash(ciphertextBytes);
                byte[] signature = rSAProviderThis.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1"));
                return signature;
            }
        }
        public void Verify()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```

Second question : how do i send and receive  data to be fed into the class ? i'm a green horn in this field, pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would make the encrypt/sign/decrypt/verify methods take parameters for the data rather than having member variables for them. Having member variables for the key and provider seems okay though. Basically I'd expect to use the same key multiple times but not the same data.

I'd also make it immutable - make all the variables readonly, taking all the parameters you'll need for the providers in the constructor instead of having a separate initialisation method.

Beyond that, it seems okay to wrap the functionality in a simpler API for your needs though, yes.

Comment: Thanks Jon, making the plaintextByte a member variable adds unnecessary restriction, should have noticed it.

Answer (score 2):

I have made some adjustments, here is what the implementation looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Agnus.Cipher
{
    public class RSA : IDisposable
    {
        private RSACryptoServiceProvider rSAProviderThis;
        private RSACryptoServiceProvider rSAProviderOther = null;

        public string PublicKey
        {
            get { return rSAProviderThis.ToXmlString(false); }
        }

        public RSA()
        {
            rSAProviderThis = new RSACryptoServiceProvider { PersistKeyInCsp = true }; 
        }

        public void InitializeRSAProviderOther(string parameters)
        {
            rSAProviderOther.FromXmlString(parameters);
        }

        public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] plaintextBytes)
        {
                return rSAProviderThis.Encrypt(plaintextBytes, true);
        }
        public string  Decrypt(byte[] ciphertextBytes)
        {
            try
            {
                return Convert.ToBase64String( rSAProviderThis.Decrypt(ciphertextBytes, true));
            }
            catch (CryptographicException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to decrypt: " + ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Dispose();
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
        public string SignData(byte[] ciphertextBytes)
        {
            string  signature = GenerateSignature(ciphertextBytes, rSAProviderThis);
            return signature;
        }

        private string GenerateSignature(byte[] ciphertextBytes, RSACryptoServiceProvider provider)
        {
            using (SHA1Managed SHA1 = new SHA1Managed())
            {
                byte[] hash = SHA1.ComputeHash(ciphertextBytes);
                string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(provider.SignHash(hash, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA1")));
                return signature;
            }

        }

        public string  VerifySignature(byte[] ciphertextBytes, string parameters, string signatureToVerify)
        {
            InitializeRSAProviderOther(parameters);
            string actualSignature = GenerateSignature(ciphertextBytes, rSAProviderOther);
            if (actualSignature.Equals(signatureToVerify))
            {
                //verification successful
                string decryptedData = this.Decrypt(ciphertextBytes);
                return decryptedData;
                //decryptedData is a symmetric key
            }
            else
            {
                //verification unsuccessful
                //end session
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

        #region IDisposable Members

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (rSAProviderOther != null)
            {
                rSAProviderOther.Clear();
            }
            rSAProviderThis.Clear();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

you guys still haven't said anything about how communication is going to be established (i'm thinking sockets). Please enlighten me.

Comment: Network communication is an unrelated topic to "Implementing RSA in C#", so you aren't going to get people who want to talk about that here.  There are ways to get a byte[] back and forth across a Socket, yes.

Comment: coming to think of it i should be using VerifyHash(). Should save me  some lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this snip of code may help you, I've wrote this code to  be able to crypt and decrypt with private/public key pairs in diverse crypting algortims and without data to encrypt length issue, infact RSA implementation in .NET suffer whe you try to manage more than 250 (more or less, sorry I don't recall) bytes of data.

I just cut and paste only methods needed, I also cutted xml documentation cause is not in english, if you found this useful let me know, I can post all source. I repeat I do not tested this cut&paste version, but I used the full version of this class that is not that different.

BTW: it's in VB, but if you just need to lurk at it I think it's enough ;)

```
Namespace Crypto

    Public Class RSACry

        Shared Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Enum Algorithms
            DES
            TDES
            RC2
            RDAEL
        End Enum

        Public Shared Function Encrypt(ByVal xmlkeystring As String, ByVal typo As Algorithms, ByVal datatoencrypt As String) As String
            Dim rsaer As RSA = Crypto.RSACry.ReadKeyString(xmlkeystring)
            Dim result() As Byte = Crypto.RSACry.EncryptIt(rsaer, typo, datatoencrypt)
            Return System.Convert.ToBase64String(result)
        End Function

        Public Shared Function Decrypt(ByVal xmlkeystring As String, ByVal typo As Algorithms, ByVal datatodecrypt As String) As String
            Dim rsaer As RSA = Crypto.RSACry.ReadKeyString(xmlkeystring)
            Dim result() As Byte = Crypto.RSACry.DecryptIt(rsaer, typo, datatodecrypt)
            Return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result)
        End Function

        Friend Shared Function EncryptIt(ByRef rsaer As RSA, ByVal typo As Algorithms, ByVal datatoencrypt As String) As Byte()
            Dim result() As Byte = Nothing

            Try
                Dim plainbytes() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(datatoencrypt)
                Dim sa As SymmetricAlgorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(Crypto.RSACry.GetAlgorithmName(typo))
                Dim ct As ICryptoTransform = sa.CreateEncryptor()
                Dim encrypt() As Byte = ct.TransformFinalBlock(plainbytes, 0, plainbytes.Length)
                Dim fmt As RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter = New RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter(rsaer)
                Dim keyex() As Byte = fmt.CreateKeyExchange(sa.Key)

                --return the key exchange, the IV (public) and encrypted data 
                result = New Byte(keyex.Length + sa.IV.Length + encrypt.Length) {}
                Buffer.BlockCopy(keyex, 0, result, 0, keyex.Length)
                Buffer.BlockCopy(sa.IV, 0, result, keyex.Length, sa.IV.Length)
                Buffer.BlockCopy(encrypt, 0, result, keyex.Length + sa.IV.Length, encrypt.Length)

            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New CryptographicException("Unable to crypt: " + ex.Message)
            End Try

            Return result
        End Function

        Friend Shared Function DecryptIt(ByRef rsaer As RSA, ByVal typo As Algorithms, ByVal datatodecrypt As String) As Byte()
            Dim result() As Byte = Nothing

            Try
                Dim encrbytes() As Byte = System.Convert.FromBase64String(datatodecrypt)
                Dim sa As SymmetricAlgorithm = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(Crypto.RSACry.GetAlgorithmName(typo))
                Dim keyex() As Byte = New Byte((rsaer.KeySize >> 3) - 1) {}
                Buffer.BlockCopy(encrbytes, 0, keyex, 0, keyex.Length)

                Dim def As RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter = New RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter(rsaer)
                Dim key() As Byte = def.DecryptKeyExchange(keyex)
                Dim iv() As Byte = New Byte((sa.IV.Length - 1)) {}
                Buffer.BlockCopy(encrbytes, keyex.Length, iv, 0, iv.Length)

                Dim ct As ICryptoTransform = sa.CreateDecryptor(key, iv)
                result = ct.TransformFinalBlock(encrbytes, keyex.Length + iv.Length, (encrbytes.Length - 1) - (keyex.Length + iv.Length))
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New CryptographicException("Unable to decrypt: " + ex.Message)
            End Try

            Return result
        End Function    

        Friend Shared Function GetAlgorithmName(ByVal typo As Algorithms) As String
            Dim algtype As String = String.Empty

            Select Case typo
                Case Algorithms.DES
                    Return "DES"
                    Exit Select
                Case Algorithms.RC2
                    Return "RC2"
                    Exit Select
                Case Algorithms.RDAEL
                    Return "Rijndael"
                    Exit Select
                Case Algorithms.TDES
                    Return "TripleDES"
                    Exit Select
                Case Else
                    Return "Rijndael"
                    Exit Select
            End Select

            Return algtype
        End Function

        Friend Shared Function ReadKeyString(ByVal xmlkeystring As String) As RSA
            Dim rsaer As RSA = Nothing

            Try
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlkeystring)) Then Throw New Exception("Key is not specified")
                rsaer = RSA.Create()
                rsaer.FromXmlString(xmlkeystring)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Throw New CryptographicException("Unable to load key")
            End Try

            Return rsaer
        End Function    

End Namespace
```

Comment: Thanks Andrea, your code has been of great help. Could you post all of it? tell me did you use some sort of sockets class to send and receive public keys and encrypted data ?

Answer (score 1):

@gogole:
actually I don't use sockets, this code is used in stand alone way with keys hand-bringed.
However once you have your crypt mechanism, you're at more than half of the journey.

Here there are two missing methods to create keys, as you requested the code is complete.
I hope you found this helpful

```
Public Shared Sub CreateKeyPair(ByVal filename As String)
    Dim xmlpublic As String = String.Empty
    Dim xmlprivate As String = String.Empty

    CreateKeyPair(xmlpublic, xmlprivate)

    Try
        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(filename + ".prv")
        writer.Write(xmlprivate)
        writer.Flush()
        writer.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New CryptographicException("Unable to write private key file: " + ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        Dim writer = New StreamWriter(filename + ".pub")
        writer.Write(xmlpublic)
        writer.Flush()
        writer.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New CryptographicException("Unable to write public key file: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Public Shared Sub CreateKeyPair(ByRef xmlpublic As String, ByRef xmlprivate As String)
    Dim rsa As RSA = Nothing

    Try
        rsa.Create()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New CryptographicException("Unable to initialize keys: " + ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        xmlpublic = rsa.ToXmlString(True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New CryptographicException("Unable to generate public key: " + ex.Message)
    End Try

    Try
        xmlprivate = rsa.ToXmlString(False)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New CryptographicException("Unable to generate private key: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not know much vb but tried to convert @Andrea Celin one of useful Code in c#

```
namespace Crypto
{
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
class RSACry
{
    public enum Algorithms
    {
        DES,
        TDES,
        RC2,
        RDAEL
    };
    public string Encrypt(string xmlkeystring, Algorithms typo, string datatoencrypt)
    {
        RSA rsaer = RSACry.ReadKeyString(xmlkeystring);
        byte[] result = RSACry.EncryptIt(rsaer, typo, datatoencrypt);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(result);
    }

    public string Decrypt(string xmlkeystring,Algorithms typo,string datatodecrypt)
    {
        RSA rsaer = RSACry.ReadKeyString(xmlkeystring);
        byte[] result =RSACry.DecryptIt(rsaer, typo, datatodecrypt);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
    }

    public static byte[] EncryptIt(RSA rsaer, Algorithms typo, string datatoencrypt)
    {
        byte[] result = null;
        try
        {
            byte[] plainbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(datatoencrypt);
            SymmetricAlgorithm sa = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(RSACry.GetAlgorithmName(typo));
            ICryptoTransform ct = sa.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] encrypt = ct.TransformFinalBlock(plainbytes, 0, plainbytes.Length);
            RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter fmt = new RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter(rsaer);
            byte[] keyex = fmt.CreateKeyExchange(sa.Key);

            //--return the key exchange, the IV (public) and encrypted data 
            result = new byte[keyex.Length + sa.IV.Length + encrypt.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(keyex, 0, result, 0, keyex.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(sa.IV, 0, result, keyex.Length, sa.IV.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encrypt, 0, result, keyex.Length + sa.IV.Length, encrypt.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Unable to crypt: " + ex.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static byte[] DecryptIt(RSA rsaer, Algorithms typo, string datatodecrypt)
    {
        byte[] result = null;

        try
        {
            byte[] encrbytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(datatodecrypt);
            SymmetricAlgorithm sa = SymmetricAlgorithm.Create(RSACry.GetAlgorithmName(typo));
            byte[] keyex = new byte[(rsaer.KeySize >> 3) - 1];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encrbytes, 0, keyex, 0, keyex.Length);

            RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter def = new RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeDeformatter(rsaer);
            byte[] key = def.DecryptKeyExchange(keyex);
            byte[] iv = new byte[sa.IV.Length - 1];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(encrbytes, keyex.Length, iv, 0, iv.Length);

            ICryptoTransform ct = sa.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
            result = ct.TransformFinalBlock(encrbytes, keyex.Length + iv.Length, (encrbytes.Length - 1) - (keyex.Length + iv.Length));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Unable to decrypt: " + ex.Message);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string GetAlgorithmName(Algorithms typo)
    {
        string algtype = String.Empty;
        switch(typo)
        {
            case Algorithms.DES:
                algtype = "DES";
                break;
            case Algorithms.RC2:
                algtype = "RC2";
                break;
            case Algorithms.RDAEL:
                algtype = "Rijndael";
                break;
            case Algorithms.TDES:
                algtype = "TripleDES";
                break;
            default:
                algtype = "Rijndael";
                break;
        }
        return algtype;
    }

    public static RSA ReadKeyString(string xmlkeystring)
    {
        RSA rsaer = null;
        try
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlkeystring))
            { throw new Exception("Key is not specified"); }
            rsaer = RSA.Create();
            rsaer.FromXmlString(xmlkeystring);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new CryptographicException("Unable to load key :"+ex.Message);
        }
        return rsaer;
    }
}
}
```