# Using RSA in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography

How to encrypt a text or any other media using RSA cryptography in C# ? .

Do i need to use any external libraries or are there any in-build stuff ?  A small sample code will help!

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/RSACryptoPad.aspx  has some nice examples on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx).

The linked site contains an example.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some code snippets from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384401/implementing-rsa-in-c) and [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/RSACryptoPad.aspx).