# how i can get the private key of my certificate to encrypt text with RSA in c#?

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is possible to encrypt with private key using .net RSACryptoServiceProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181421/is-possible-to-encrypt-with-private-key-using-net-rsacryptoserviceprovider)

Hello every one
I made a certificate and 
how i can get the private key of my certificate to encrypt text with RSA in c#?

Answer (score 2):

Private key does not encrypt. The Private Key's purpose is to decrypt and the Public Key's purpose is to encrypt. Usually the only time you would encrypt with the private key is during a signing process.

You can read more on [Public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#Description) at Wikipedia.

Comment: Note, You need the other party's public key to encrypt. Not your own one.

Comment: @IanNorton: Yes, they are key pairs.

Comment: correct, but you only need one key to encrypt for. You need not have your own.

Answer (score 0):

Looks rather similar to this [Using RSA in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698161/using-rsa-in-c) previous question.